# Can not download Excel and DataBase in R but CSV works

Tags: r, excel, rcurl

I am going through "R is for Everyone" and on 6.2 it is asking to download an excel file online. I was able to do it when they asked to download a CSV, but I get error messages for Excel.

Downloading the CSV online works, Excel doesn't work. I tried doing the DB portion a few pages later and still some problems. I believe I've downloaded all packages but perhaps I'm missing something.

This is the code I am using:

```
download.file(url='http://jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx', destfile = 'data/ExcelExample.xlsx', method = 'curl')

download.file("http://www.jaredlander.com/data/diamonds.db", destfile = "data\diamonds.db",mode ='wb')
```

I expected for it to download the Excel file, however I received the below error message.

> Warning: Failed to create the file data/ExcelExample.xlsx: No such
>   file or  Warning: directory 100   254  100   254    0     0    537
>   0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   538 curl: (23) Failed writing body (0
>   != 254) Error in download.file(url =
>   "http://jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx",  :    'curl' call had
>   nonzero exit status

As well as this for DB portion.

```
1: In download.file("http://www.jaredlander.com/data/diamonds.db",  :
  URL http://www.jaredlander.com/data/diamonds.db: cannot open destfile 'data/diamonds.db', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In download.file("http://www.jaredlander.com/data/diamonds.db",  :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

Comment: Is it possible you do not have a local `data` directory?

Comment: Hi, just remove ``method =`` and tell me the result please. ``download.file(url='http://jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx', destfile = 'data/ExcelExample.xlsx')``.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
target = "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/meisubs.NSF/log?openagent&5206001_key_aggregates.xls&5206.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&24FF946FB10A10CDCA258192001DAC4B&0&Jun%202017&06.09.2017&Latest"
dest = 'downloaded_file.xls'

download.file(url = target, destfile = dest, mode='wb')
```

Or, you can do this.

```
library(readxl)
library(httr)
packageVersion("readxl")
url = "https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/W_EPC0_SAX_YCUOK_MBBLw.xls"

GET(url, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
df <- read_excel(tf, 2L)
str(df)
```